# how to use mutationobserver with youtube spa technology in javascript

Tags: javascript, performance, url, youtube, single-page-application

I want the video in a youtube playlist to go to the next video when it reaches the second I want. But I can't check the `location.href` all the time, I want the code to run when the same url is opened again because I loop the playlist.

```js
const counterEle = document.querySelector("video");

function generateCount(limit) {
  mutation(160.510023);

  if (counterEle.currentTime > limit) {
    console.log("current > limit");
  } else {
    setTimeout(generateCount, 3000, limit);
    setTimeout(mutation, 3000, limit);
  }
}


let previousUrl = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=93qE6Z8qheA&list=PL9dIg-VwAsxZdZvuHjzTOP8-49CWpis17&index=5';
const observer = new MutationObserver(mutation);

function mutation(limit) {
  generateCount(160.510023);
  if (location.href == previousUrl) {
    console.log(`URL changed to ${location.href}`);
    if (counterEle.currentTime > limit) {
      document
        .querySelector(
          "#movie_player > div.ytp-chrome-bottom > div.ytp-chrome-controls > div.ytp-left-controls > a.ytp-next-button.ytp-button"
        )
        .click();
    } else {
      setTimeout(generateCount, 3000);
    }
    } else {
      console.log("!=");
    }
}
```

I tried many methods, what am I doing wrong?

(There is no problem with the code working, just checking the domain name is a problem)

Comment: Try this: don't check if the video reaches a given time (*i.e. `if (counterEle.currentTime > limit) {`*) and instead call your method `mutation` with `setTimeout(<your_method>, <set_milliseconds_here>);` and store the url of the playlist when a new video plays, then, loop this new array and check if the url was already added in the array - adding the logic you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ontimeupdate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/timeupdate_event) on the `video` html media element. This way, you get notified when the currentTime is changing.

Also you can check if an ad is playing using `document.querySelector('.ad-interrupting')`

The following code will play the next element in the playlist after 5 seconds:

```js
const specificTime = 5; //play next after 5 seconds
const vid = document.querySelector("video");
vid.ontimeupdate = function onTimeUpdate(){
    var ad = document.querySelector('.ad-interrupting');
    if (!ad && vid.currentTime >= specificTime){
        console.log("playing next");
        document.querySelector(
            "#movie_player > div.ytp-chrome-bottom > div.ytp-chrome-controls > div.ytp-left-controls > a.ytp-next-button.ytp-button"
        ).click();
    }
}
```

Tampermonkey script example:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         autoplay next video in playslist
// @version      0.1
// @description  play next video in playlist after X seconds
// @include      /https:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/watch?.*list=PL9dIg-VwAsxZdZvuHjzTOP8-49CWpis17.*/
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    const specificTime = 5; //play next after 5 seconds
    const vid = document.querySelector("video");
    vid.ontimeupdate = function onTimeUpdate(){
        var ad = document.querySelector('.ad-interrupting');
        if (!ad && vid.currentTime >= specificTime){
            console.log("playing next");
            document.querySelector(
                "#movie_player > div.ytp-chrome-bottom > div.ytp-chrome-controls > div.ytp-left-controls > a.ytp-next-button.ytp-button"
            ).click();
        }
    }
})();
```

which match [this playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WJF5Z1WRcqw&list=PL9dIg-VwAsxZdZvuHjzTOP8-49CWpis17&index=1) when activated

Comment: `if (!ad && vid.currentTime >= specificTime && document.location.href == "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=93qE6Z8qheA&list=PL9dIg-VwAsxZdZvuHjzTOP8-49CWpis17&index=5")`

When I added the field name to the if condition it worked fine, thanks